# Python imports system wide tensorflow instead of the active conda's environment version

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

I have a conda environment that, while active, keeps importing the system wide tensorflow version.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the environment specific version (with both pip and conda), but still it's always the system wide version that gets imported. This doesn't happen in other environments, so I have probably messed up the environment path somehow. Also, when I launch the python interpreter inside the conda env site-packages folder, the correct tensorflow version (environment one) is imported. By the way this is all on a cluster where I don't have root privileges. I guess I could try with a fresh environment, but I got through a bit of pain installing other packages (dependent on tf) so I'd rather fix this one if it's possible.

```
(tf_gpu) greyostrich{polymena}% conda list
# packages in environment at /data/XXX/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpu:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_tflow_select             2.1.0                       gpu  
matplotlib                3.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
mkl                       2019.1                      144  
mkl_fft                   1.0.10           py36ha843d7b_0  
mkl_random                1.0.2            py36hd81dba3_0  
mock                      3.0.5                    py36_0  
mujoco-py                 1.50.1.68                pypi_0    pypi
ncurses                   6.1                  he6710b0_1  
numpy                     1.15.4           py36h7e9f1db_0  
numpy-base                1.15.4           py36hde5b4d6_0  
openssl                   1.1.1c               h7b6447c_1  
pandas                    0.23.4                   pypi_0    pypi
pilco                     0.1                       dev_0    <develop>
pillow                    5.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       19.1.1                   pypi_0    pypi
protobuf                  3.6.1            py36he6710b0_0  
python                    3.6.8                h0371630_0  
python-dateutil           2.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pytz                      2019.1                   pypi_0    pypi
readline                  7.0                  h7b6447c_5  
scipy                     1.1.0            py36h7c811a0_2  
setuptools                40.6.3                   py36_0  
six                       1.12.0                   py36_0  
sqlite                    3.26.0               h7b6447c_0  
tensorboard               1.13.1           py36hf484d3e_0  
tensorflow                1.13.1          gpu_py36h26cf82e_0  
tensorflow-base           1.13.1          gpu_py36h8f37b9b_0  
tensorflow-estimator      1.13.0                     py_0  
tensorflow-gpu            1.13.1               h0d30ee6_0  
tensorflow-probability    0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 1.1.0                    py36_1  
tk                        8.6.8                hbc83047_0  
werkzeug                  0.14.1                   py36_0  
wheel                     0.32.3                   py36_0  
xz                        5.2.4                h14c3975_4  
zlib                      1.2.11               h7b6447c_3
```

From python:

```
Python 3.6.8 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec 30 2018, 01:22:34) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
>>> print(get_python_lib())
/data/XXX/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages
>>> import tensorflow
>>> tensorflow.__version__
'1.10.0'
>>> tensorflow.__file__
'/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py'
```

After `cd /data/XXX/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages`:

```
Python 3.6.8 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec 30 2018, 01:22:34) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
>>> tensorflow.__version__
'1.13.1'
>>> tensorflow.__file__
'/data/XXX/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py'
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you activated your environment?

Comment: Yes, this all happens when the environment is active. Still I think you might be up to something: when I first login to the cluster, the conda command is not found, same as ```source activate```. After I manually do ```source ~/.bashrc```, the base environment gets active, and from there on conda and source can be used.

Comment: Small update, the bash_profile thing seems to be unrelated, the problem persisted no matter what I did with the dot files. For now, I am working with a fresh env where the original issue didn't appear.